# Using cut to Convert Pipe-Delimited to Comma-Delimited

Tags: bash, delimiter, cut

I have an input csv that is pipe-delimited that I want to select a few columns from then save as a comma-delimited file.

Using the code below I can read the input csv and save the selected columns as a new csv, but it is still pipe-delimited:

```
cut -d "|" -f1-2,15,28-31,35 < input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

when I try to use the `output-delimiter` option I get an illegal option error.

I tried:

```
cut -d "|" -f1-2,15,28-31,35 --output-delimiter="," < input_file.csv > output_file.cv
```

and

```
cut -d "|" -f1-2,15,28-31,35 < input_file.csv > output_file.csv --output-delimiter=","
```

But I get an error

```
cut: illegal option -- -
usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]
```

Comment: Why don't you translate? `tr '|' ,`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Because I don't know what that is.

Comment: Then go read `man tr`.

Comment: Try putting `--output-delimiter=","` right after `-d "|"`

Comment: @Marichyasana Same error

Comment: @4ae1e1 Thank you for the tr heads-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `cut` doesn't understand the `--output-delimiter` directive. Are you sure that you have a version of `cut` that does?

One idea is to first translate the `|` into `,`, then cut that:

```
tr '|' ',' < input_file.csv | cut -d ',' -f1-2,15,28-31,35 > output_file.csv
```

Another option would be `awk`, which understands different field delimiters for input and output:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"; OFS=","} 
           {print $1, $2, $15, $28, $29, $30, $31, $35}' \
     < input_file.csv >output_file.csv
```

Cheers